# JavaFX function takes any javaFX component?

Tags: java, generics, javafx

i wanna make a function that takes any javaFX element and sets an onMouseEntered event.

I tried to use generic type and extended it with only javaFX textfield but when i try to access the setOnMouseEntered method it says "Cannot resolve method 'setOnMouseEntered' in 'T'". How can i do that ?

```
public class sceneHandler<T extends javafx.scene.control.TextField> {
    public <T> void onMouseUI(T obj){
            obj.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
               // Do something
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with Node?

Comment: The error was occurring because you defined `T` once at the class level, then created a new, overriding definition of `T` in the method signature.  But as others have pointed out, you don’t need generics at all for this.

Comment: java naming conventions, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Node class, which is the base class for all JavaFX components:

```
public void onMouseUI(Node node){
     node.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
         // Do something
     });
}
```

Comment: I think generics are now unnecessary

Comment: I see the value of generics for collections, but not in this case. There is already a common superobject (Node) and inheritance works fine in this case.